# How to convert the winding of a radial electric motor to a linear tubular electric motor?

Tags: motor, design, brushless-dc-motor, linear, winding

There are winding scheme/calculators and tutorials online for conventional electric motors, but I can't find any clear method of wind linear tubular electric motors.

For example, this is the winding of a conventional electric motor:

[image: Electric motor winding]

But when I try to search for linear tubular electric motors, I can only find images like this:

[image: Tubular linear motor]

It shows that it has 3 phases, but not how they are connected to one another.

---

Is there a way of converting the winding of a conventional motor to a linear tubular motor?

Comment: make a cut between poles 1 and 45 in the top picture and unroll the circumference into a straight  line

Comment: @jsotola that would make a linear motor, but not a tubular linear motor.

Comment: you asked `how they are connected to one another?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picture is a model to show the concept.  For the model you have shown:

The gray are magnets, magnetized radially with alternating polarity.

The red, yellow and blue are windings.  They are all wound in radially in the same direction, and all of the windings of each color will be in series.  The "start" ends are your inputs, and the "finish" ends are the wye connections.

Conceptually, this would be analogous to a four-pole, six slot brushless motor (or any brushless motor with a 4:6 pole:slot ratio.